# Maven web project issue

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

I'm using Eclipse IDE for EE development(Kepler SR1).

Using Maven 3.1.0, I'm trying to create a simple web project. Accordingly, in Eclipse, I select **maven-archetype-webapp and proceed.**

But when the project is created, under 'Java resources', only **src/main/resources is seen**. When I check the build path, it shows **src/main/java and src/test/java as missing**.

Obviously, when I created a simple servlet under src/main/resources, I got a ClassNotFoundException for the servlet - I believe that the Servlet class didn't get compiled as my Maven basic folder structure itself is missing !

What could be the problem? I don't see any reason to make/create any source folder entries manually if I'm getting the option of 'maven-archetype-webapp' in the Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-bundles/maven-archetype-webapp/) to suggest that the `maven-archetype-webapp` archetype will create a servlet class for you.

The documentation for this archetype shows this structure as the end result:

```
project
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- webapp
            |-- WEB-INF
            |   `-- web.xml
            `-- index.jsp
```

The archetype description does state that is a "*An archetype which contains a sample Maven Webapp project.*", and it certainly is.

You'll need to use another archetype, or create your own. An alternative approach is the Eclipse WTP integration to eclipse-ify your maven project. It's been a while since I tried, but iirc that worked pretty well.

Comment: Yeah I know that servlet won't be created auto. The issue is that the maven folder structure is not getting created properly(please check my post's initial part) but I'm not getting any error.